# How to render a directive to a HTML string in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

Using Angular, I am trying to dynamically generate an svg using a directive.

I have a directive called `<svg-directive>` with a template containing a valid xml svg definition with some scope variables. If I include `<svg-directive></svg-directive>` in my template it displays just fine.

In my page controller, I would like to retrieve a compiled string of my svg directive with all the scope variables populated (the goal is to send this string to a REST API with a HTTP POST).

In my controller I have the following code:

```
var compiled = $compile("<svg-directive></svg-directive>")($scope);

$timeout(function() {
    var svgEl = compiled[0].querySelector("svg");
    var svgStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgEl);
    console.log(svgStr);
}, 0);
```

When I load this controller the first time, I get:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

On the `var svgEl = compiled[0].querySelector("svg");` line.

However, once on the page, if I click refresh the error goes away and the `svgStr` contents is successfully logged to the screen.

My question is: How can I get the directives HTML to serialize correctly the first time the controller is loaded?

PS. Any suggestions to improving my approach to getting the directives rendered HTML are also welcome.

Comment: Maybe you can add a callback function in the post link event of your svg-directive. This way you can call your function once the directive has succesfully compiled.

Comment: @DanielHigueras, I am trying that but the `element` I return to my callback function doesn't contain the scope variables if I try element[0].querySelector("svg").

Comment: If you provide a working plnkr I can try to do an example for you